# Does Anti-Matter follow the same laws as Physics, but oppositely?

Tags: antimatter

Matter follows the laws of physics, so does anti-matter react oppositely to these laws, or does it have its own laws?

I understand that anti-matter has opposite charge, spin, etc. than matter, but does that mean that the laws it follows are also opposite to the known laws of physics or are there completely different laws?

Comment: Antimatter follows the exact same physical laws as regular matter. Some numbers used in those laws (like the charge) are flipped, that's all.

Answer (score 3):

Antimatter particles follow the same laws of physics as matter. The reason that it is assigned those particular values of charge, spin, etc. is precisely so you can use the same set of physical laws.

Take the example of an electron and positron moving through a magnetic field. You will find, observationally, that they curve in opposite directions. I suppose you could say that a positron has an anti-negative charge and accompany it with an appropriate reformulation of E&M, but it is better just to say it is positively charged. Additionally, there isn't a difference between the positive charge of a positron, and the positive charge of any normal matter particle, so there is no reason to call it something else.

However, antimatter particles don't always behave oppositely to matter. Consider mass and gravity. Both matter and antimatter have conventional, positive masses, and as such behave in exactly the same way when it comes to gravitational forces.

Comment: It would be good to mention that antimatter particles have the same mass as their counterparts, so they most likely (barring a very surprising experimental result) move the same way in gravity.

Comment: I agree. The change has been made.